# Bring a program to foreground or start it

Tags: powershell

For a handful of programs I use frequently, I am trying to write me some functions or aliases which would check if this program is already running and bring its window to foreground, else start this program.

Usage example with `np`, a handle for `notepad.exe`:

```
PS> np
```

checks if `notepad.exe` is running (`Get-Process -Name "notepad.exe"`) if not, it would start it. When Notepad is already running but my maximized console is in the foreground, I'd like to execute the same command again, but this time I want it to bring the already running notepad process to foreground, rather than start a new one.

In order to implement this, I created this class called `Program` which I would instantiate for every program I want to handle like this. Then I have a HashTable `$knownprograms` of instances of this class, and in the end I try to define functions for every program, so that I could just type two or three letters to the console to start a program or bring its running process back to foreground.

```
class Program {
        [string]$Name
        [string]$Path
        [string]$Executable
        [string[]]$Arguments
        Program(
            [string]$n,
            [string]$p,
            [string]$e,
            [string[]]$a
        ){
                $this.Name = $n
                $this.Path = $p
                $this.Executable = $e
                $this.Arguments = $a
        }
        [string]FullPath(){
                return ("{0}\{1}" -f $this.Path, $this.Executable)
        }
        [void]ShowOrStart(){
            try {
                    # Adapted from https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/bringing-window-in-the-foreground
                    $Process = Get-Process -Name $this.Name -ErrorAction Stop
                    Write-Host "Found at least one process called $this.Name"
                    $sig = '
                    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
                    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);
                    '
                    $Mode = 4 # Will restore the window, not maximize it
                    $type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -Name WindowAPI -PassThru
                    $hwnd = $process.MainWindowHandle
                    $null = $type::ShowWindowAsync($hwnd, $Mode)
                    $null = $type::SetForegroundWindow($hwnd) 
            } catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ProcessCommandException] {
                    Write-Host "Did not find any process called $this.Name"
                    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { & $this.FullPath() $this.Arguments }
            }
        }
}

$knownprograms = @{}
$knownprograms.Add("np", [Program]::new(
    "np",
    "$Env:SystemRoot\System32",
    "notepad.exe",
    @())
)
$knownprograms.Add("pt", [Program]::new(
    "pt",
    "$Env:SystemRoot\System32",
    "mspaint.exe",
    @())
)

Function np {
        [cmdletbinding()]
        Param()
        $knownprograms.np.ShowOrStart()
}
Function pt {
        [cmdletbinding()]
        Param()
        $knownprograms.pt.ShowOrStart()
}
```

The idea would be that I would source this script in my `profile.ps1` and then just use the pre-factored functions. However, it seems that this code always opens a new instance of the program, rather than using its running process. Maybe I need some sort of delayed evaluation, so that the `ShowOrStart()` method checks at the time of invocation of `np` or `pt` whether the associated process exists. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process name for `notepad.exe` is `notepad`.
Update

```
$knownprograms.Add("np", [Program]::new(
    "notepad",
    "$Env:SystemRoot\System32",
    "notepad.exe",
    @())
)
```

And this works as expected.

This would be probably interesting to register `$sig` once for all and not on every call (which will probably raise an error).

Comment: You are right. My error was actually just a bad attribute naming. Program.Name is actually what is later being searched for in the processes, and of course one cannot find a process named `np` or `pt`. I renamed it to Program.Searchstring. And instead of the many lines starting with `$sig`, I could have just used `(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).AppActivate($this.proc.MainWindowTitle)`, as JSanders pointed out 6 years ago in a comment on the very page where I took the lines from.